# Paypal single payout: TRANSACTION_LIMIT_EXCEEDED API Error

Tags: node.js, api, paypal

I'm trying to make a [singe payout with the REST API of PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payouts/single-payout/#create-a-single-payout) with Node.js and get this error:

```
//...
"errors": {
        "name": "TRANSACTION_LIMIT_EXCEEDED",
        "message": "Either the sender or receiver exceeded the transaction limit",
}
//...
```

What I do:

I use this [example Code](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/blob/master/samples/payout/create_single_payout.js):

```
var paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk');

module.exports = {
    payMe: function (req, res,next) {

        var mail = req.param('mail'); //this email comes from the paypal sandbox

        paypal.configure({
            'mode': 'sandbox',
            'client_id': 'mycliendID',
            'client_secret': 'myClientSecret'
        });

        var sender_batch_id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(9);

        var create_payout_json = {
            "sender_batch_header": {
                "sender_batch_id": sender_batch_id,
                "email_subject": "You have a payment"
            },
            "items": [
                {
                    "recipient_type": "EMAIL",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": 0.90,
                        "currency": "CHF" //changed from Dollar to CHF
                    },
                    "receiver": mail,
                    "note": "Thank you.",
                    "sender_item_id": "item_3"
                }
            ]
        };

        var sync_mode = 'true'; //for single payout

        paypal.payout.create(create_payout_json, sync_mode, function (error, payout) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error.response);
                res.json(error.response);
                throw error;
            } else {
                console.log("Create Single Payout Response");
                console.log(payout);
                payout.status= "You are in the else";
                res.json(payout);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

=>The Email-Address comes from my [sandbox account](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/) - the Balance of this User is set to 900.00 CHF! (Much more than the 0.90 CHF which I want to payout)

=>I created under [My Apps and Credentials](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/) a new REST API App and select the previous created User (with 900.00CHF balance). Those credentials are used in the above code snipped in paypal.configure()

> "Either the sender or receiver exceeded the transaction limit"

Where can I change the transaction limit for the App and User in the sandbox?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK Solved.

I logged in with the sandbox email address - there you can see all transactions.

Under "Denied" I saw the 0.90CHF - With a popup: "The receiver decided to deny the payment"

Then I realised that I used the same E-Mail Address for the Receiver and the Sender. That accused the Error. - The error-message is not very clear.

Maybe someone else is also doing the same mistake, so I let this here.